# Can't stop xampp apache service from running

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

When i try to stop the xampp apache from running, I get this error: "Error -1".

What does error mean and do I solve it?

It is important to close the apache service while not using any program that needs a local host?

Why I can still enter local host on the browser after closing xampp by pressing the exit button?